# I want to represent int value as color in js

Tags: javascript

I get a value from db.I want if the value is one to display a green circle and if zero to show a red circle.

```
var online= $("#online").val();
if (online = 1) {
    online = RGBColour(255, 0, 0);
} else {
    online = RGBColour(0, 255, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value not checking for value. You need to check with either == or === like below:

```
 var online= $("#online").val();
 if (online == 1) { //Or, just if(online){
    online = RGBColour(255, 0, 0);
 } else {
    online = RGBColour(0, 255, 0);
 }
```

Comment: its just displaying the value i.e 1 or 0.I want it to display a color

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`if (online = 1) {`

with

`if (online == 1) {`

Comment: correct JS would ensure that `.val()` is of valid number type and then use `===` instead.  Using `==` is just lazy.

Comment: its just displaying the value i.e 1 or 0.I want it to display a color